# Where i can give return values below given script?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting..
i tried one script with using bash functions...but i don't know how to give return values..anyone help me..

```
                    #!/bin/bash
                   #Example of menu programs
                    function file_directory () {
                    while true;
                    do
                    echo "*******************"
                    echo "1.Date"
                    echo "2.List of users"
                    echo "3.Open a file"
                    echo "4.delete a file"
                    echo "5.Exit"
                    echo "Enter a choice[1-5] :"
                    read choice
                    case $choice in
                    1) echo "Today date is : `date`" 
                         return 0;;
                    2) who 
                       return 0 ;;
                    3) `touch file`  
                        return 0;;
                    4) `rm -rf kk`
                            return 0;;
                    5) exit 
                        return 0 ;;
                    *) echo "choice wrong. try again"
                        return 1 ;;
                    esac
                    done
                    }
                   ## Main script starts here
                   file_directory

                    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
                     echo "success"
                    elif [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
                     echo "Something went wrong"
                    else
                        echo "failed"
                    fi
```

Above shell script what i tried.....help me

Comment: Have you tried `return`?

Comment: @Siguza Yes, i tried but i am giving wrong places so try to help me where i can give to return values.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you cannot use `$?` multiple times, because it is set to the result of the **last** command. Also, you are comparing numeric 0 with string "0" and operator -eq (which wants a value, not a string), what is not right. Try:

```
retval=$?

if [ $retval -eq 0 ]; ...
```

Comment: Best practice is to not use all-uppercase variable names, as they may inadvertently clash with system variables.  Use `$retval` or  `$RetVal`.

Comment: @rojomoke: Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several superfluous features which prevent it from working and/or needlessly complicate it.

Because every code path in the `case` statement ends with a `return` statement, the `while true` loop actually never loops. Take that away and you can remove the  explicit `return` statements, too, which is actually an improvemeny, as you will no  longer be  masking away any error status from the programs you call.

Also, the  process substitutions around some of the commands are incorrect. To touch a file, it's `touch file`, not `` `touch file` ``. The latter will actually retrieve the output  from the command (usually an empty string) and attempt to execute *that* as a command, which is certainly not what you want here, and an error.

Finally, explicitly examining the return code `$?` is rarely necessary -- the control flow statements of the shell already do this implicitly. So rather than `command; if [ $? = 0 ]; then something; fi` is usually written `if command; then something; fi` or even simply in  shorthand `command && something` instead.

Wrapping up, your fixed script might look something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

function file_directory () {
    cat <<'____’
*******************
 1.Date
 2.List of users
 3.Open a file
 4.delete a file
 5.Exit
Enter a choice[1-5]:
____
    read choice
    case $choice in
     1) echo "Today date is : `date`" ;;
     2) who ;;
     3) touch file ;;
     4) rm -rf kk ;;
     5) exit ;;
     *) echo "choice wrong. try again"
           file_directory ;;
    esac
}

if file_directory; then
     echo "success"
else
     echo "Something went wrong"
fi
```